# Start a service when activity is opened

Tags: android, android-service

How do i start a service when an activity is opened, I am using intent but the service isn't starting at all. Music is meant to be played when a certain page is opened, but no service is running at all.

This is the code i am using to start the service on the MainPage class.

```
public class BackgroundMusic extends Service implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks, Runnable {

MediaPlayer player;

private static final Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.backgroundmusic);
    player.setLooping(true);
    player.setVolume(100, 100);
    player.start();
    Intent BackgrndMusic = new Intent(this, MainPage.class);
    startService(BackgrndMusic);
    getApplication().registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // stop listening for activities
    getApplication().unregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
    // do not destroy this service
    uiHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
}

@Override
public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
    // if an activity don't show up in 1 second, destroy this service
    uiHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // no more activity, destroy this service
    stopSelf();
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent BackgrndMusic = new Intent(BackgroundMusic.this, MainPage.class);
    startService(BackgrndMusic);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
    Intent BackgrndMusic = new Intent(BackgroundMusic.this, MainPage.class);
    startService(BackgrndMusic);
}

@Override
public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
    Intent BackgrndMusic = new Intent(BackgroundMusic.this, MainPage.class);
    stopService(BackgrndMusic);
}

@Override
public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {

}

@Override
public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
    Intent BackgrndMusic = new Intent(BackgroundMusic.this, MainPage.class);
    stopService(BackgrndMusic);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the MainPage code ?

Comment: The main page is just an activity page, where i want my music playing. I set the music in the BackgroundMusic service class.

Comment: Sorry I meant can you post the BackgroundMusic code

Comment: Ive editied it for you with the whole code

Comment: where is `startService()` being called? How do you start your `Service`?

Comment: This code makes no sense at all. You say in the text that this is the code you use to start your `Service` in an `Activity`. And yet, the code is from a `Service`, not an `Activity`. Also, in `onCreate()` you call `startService` but pass an `Intent` that contains `MainPage.class`, which you say is an `Activity`. Please post the correct code.

Comment: The startService is in the onActivityCreated which is meant to check whether the activity is open to start the service. It isn't meant to be in the onCreate. The reason I am attempting it like this, is so i wont have to start, pause and stop the service on every page i want it running.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
super.onResume();
startService(foo);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
 super.onDestroy();
 StopService(foo);
}
```

Comment: what if i only want it playing when one activity is opened?

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on what you're trying to do in your application.

Comment: so when the MainPage is opened music should play, and should continue on a few pages without any interruptions. Using a service was recormended to me in this format, ive editied it to display the whole BackgroundMusic class code.